# numpy.savez nonblocking i/o; possible?

Tags: python, numpy, io, cython

I've got some long-running, tight-loop, number-crunching, OpenMP code running in Cython, but am dropping back into python/numpy to write checkpoints. I'm also visualizing intermediate results in the checkpoints, so they are not totally wasted.

I'm experiencing an "Amdahl's Law" slowdown in my wall-clock times because I can't figure out how to get numpy.savez (or it's cousin, numpy.savez_compressed) to do non-blocking I/O.

I've toyed with the idea of trying to use "multiprocessing" or "multithreading" to do the compression and I/O in parallel to the number crunching. (I'm leaving a couple of cores free, because the box is my main workstation.)

Before I enter that "maze of twisty passages, all alike :D " I thought I'd ask if anyone already had figured out a clean solution to such problems from within the (I)Python/Numpy/Cython ecosystem.

Thanks in advance for any advice you might be able to provide!

Frank Horowitz

Comment: Would the problem be simpler if you used `save` instead of `savez`?  `savez` creates a `zip` archive, so each array is `save'd` to separate file in the archive.  While handy for keeping related arrays together, it doesn't do anything significant performance-wise.  Just manage the collection of arrays and files yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know. I need to investigate a non-blocking file object, I suppose. Maybe a fruitful path???

Comment: Unfortunately, my ultimate workaround is not terribly general. I opted to write my checkpoints using numpy.save (i.e. uncompressed, as suggested by @hpaulj above) to a zfs filesystem with compress=lz4. That way, what's on the spinning rust is actually compressed, but that compression is performed by the zfs infrastructure in separate processes from my number crunching. So, the i/o from the number crunching perspective is non-blocking, and the (large) checkpoint data are compressed.
Maybe this will help somebody else?